# typeahead.js bloodhound minLength not working

Tags: typeahead.js, typeahead, bloodhound

I have implemented typeahead.js and bloodhound with a remote data source and it mostly works as expected. However, I have set the minLength on the typeahead to 2 and while I can see an ajax request fire after 2 characters (and 3), the typeahead only offers suggestions after 4 characters or more. Is there something missing from my config (i'm using typeahead.bundle.min.js).

```
var local_authorities = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (datum) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    identify : function(datum) {
        //console.log(datum);
        return datum.value;
    },
    remote:  {
        url: "/addresses/autocomplete_local_authorities/%QUERY",
        wildcard: '%QUERY',
        filter: function (data) {
            // Map the remote source JSON array to a JavaScript object array
            return $.map(data.local_authorities, function (local_authority) {
                return {
                    id: local_authority.id,
                    value: local_authority.name
                };
            });
        }
    }
});

$('.typeahead.local-authority').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 2,        
}, {
    limit: 8,
    source: local_authorities,
    displayKey: 'value',
})
.on('typeahead:selected', function (e, item) {
    $('[name="local_authority_ids"').val(item.id);
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you please create a demo on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Thanks. I have set up this jsfiddle but am encountering another problem: https://jsfiddle.net/zy3xtpzt/4/ I am unable to get bloodhound to submit post requests (something i originally had to work around) so it can't get data back from /echo/json in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some debugging showed that this is caused by the function `async(suggestions)` (lines 1719-1727):

```js
function async(suggestions) {
     suggestions = suggestions || [];
     if (!canceled && rendered < that.limit) {
          that.cancel = $.noop;
          rendered += suggestions.length;
          that._append(query, suggestions.slice(0, that.limit - rendered));
          that.async && that.trigger("asyncReceived", query);
     }
}
```

The bug is caused by setting `rendered` to `suggestions.length` before calling `append`, hence when Bloodhound is recieving 5 or more results for the query, `suggestions.slice(0, that.limit - rendered)` is always empty, as the standard `limit` is 5.

Suggestions are only added if the remote endpoint returns less then `limit` objects, which happens in your case for 4 letters and more.

As I'm not a developer of Typeahead nor Bloodhound, I dont want (and have the time) to figure why it has been implemented like this and how this can be fixed, however, a quick workaround is to increase `limit` .

It has to be set in the second config object, e.g. `$( "#someId" ).typeahead( { ... }, {..., limit: 10, ...});`

*EDIT: using typeahead/bloodhound v. 0.11.1*

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to debug this. Your workaround solved my problem.

Comment: It is still not fixed ... hopefully by 2020 Twitter manages to get its act together. Thou I doubt it :)